# jQuery hotkeys: prevent IE from running its own shortcuts, like Alt+H

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, keyboard-shortcuts, event-propagation

Using jQuery hotkeys, I try to bind shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to some specific actions in my site. The event propagation stops (as it should) in all browsers but IE. First of all, is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

Here is a code sample:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'Alt+H',
     function (event)
     {
        $this.toggleMenu( 'H' );
        if(jQuery.browser.msie) {
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
                    else
                    {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
        return false;
     } );
```

In IE, the line `$this.toggleMenu( 'H' );` gets executed, but then `cancelbubble` seems to have no effect (the browser opens its "Help" menu)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I would recommend a different approach.  Using the same keys that the browser, or possibly a plugin, would use is always going to be an up-hill browser.  The best implementation of keyboard shortcuts in a web app I've seen is from FogBugz which uses a single keyboard combination nothing else uses (CTRL-;) to then trigger on-screen hints for the second key to hit (without any modifier).  So instead of ALT-H it becomes CTRL-; followed by H.  http://bugs.movabletype.org/help/topics/basics/KeyboardShortcuts.html

Comment: That approach is cool, indeed, and not very difficult to implement. On the other hand, I intend to use this code to emulate a "menu" behavior in the web page; the thing is, users are already used to access menus with shortcuts like "Alt+key". If this approach proves completely wrong (for IE), I'll try the FogBugz one.

Comment: Jira (Atlassian) also uses this style of shortcuts, for example '/' to set focus to search box, 'e' to edit description, etc. In some cases I prefer that approach to using modifier keys like alt/ctrl, but of course it doesn't work if your cursor is already in a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

This is always a weird thing to attempt (due to browser's built-in hotkeys, etc), but I've had luck with using the onKeyUp event.

The problem with keydown is that it may only be sending one key at a time. So if you hit ALT it's one trigger of keydown, and then C is a second trigger. KeyPress also has probs in some environments because modifier keys like ALT and CTRL don't count as keypresses (I think.. can anybody explain this better?).

If you use keyup you can check whether ALT is being held down while also checking the key. Still working out the kinks, but try this (I only verified in win7: ie9 and chrome):

```
$(window).keyup(function (e)
{
    // warning: only tested with EN-US keyboard / locale

    // check whether ALT pressed (and not ALT+CTRL, ALT+SHIFT, etc)
    var key = e.key || String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    if (e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && key)
    {
        // if ALT pressed, handle the keycode shortcut
        var keyPressed = key.toUpperCase(); // normalize input
        switch (keyPressed)
        {
            case "C":
                // do stuff for ALT-C
                break;
            case "H":
                // do stuff for ALT-H 
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Problems/Questions:

- Uses jQuery, but pure JS solution is not too complicated
- Is it possible to prevent default browser behavior by canceling
  event?
- Will it work in browsers other than Chrome and IE9? (probably FF and
  Safari)
- If user releases ALT key BEFORE releasing the letter key, it doesn't
  work
- If user presses letter key BEFORE pressing ALT key, it doesn't work
- Tried using ACCESSKEY attributes, but that only sets focus.. I wanted
  to click a hyperlink and/or fire some element's click() event based
  on some ALT-X combination.
- While this may be acceptable for an enterprise web application (since
  locale and browser support is usually narrower focus, and since users
  are typically trained on the software), it may not be acceptable for
  web sites (due to large number of browsers in use, localization
  concerns that add to complexity, etc)... would have to think about it
  some more.

Hope this helps somebody... feel free to bring on the constructive criticism as this is a feature clients are ALWAYS asking about when I build them web apps. (they are used to the legacy form-driven apps of the 80s and 90s and want extensive keyboard support, which is understandable, especially when they pay for it!)